# How to format a partitioned sd card?

Tags: partitioning, sd-card, fdisk

I have a SD card that has several partitions on it.

Running `sudo fdisk -l` gives me:

```
        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1            8192     2121093     1056451    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2         2121728    15333375     6605824    5  Extended
/dev/mmcblk0p3        15333376    15398911       32768   83  Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p5         2129920     2252799       61440    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p6         2260992    15333375     6536192   83  Linux
```

Note all the above devices does not show up when I disconnect the SD card, hence I can assume all the above is related to the SD card.

Note the SD card is 8GB.

How can I format the SD card so that it behaves like normal?

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by 'normal'? Do you want a SD-Card with one partition of 8GB formatted in a fileformat for Ubuntu and/or Windows? If this is aht you seek, i would suggest `gparted`. Erase all partitions and create a new one with your desired filesystem.

Comment: Yes this is what I mean by normal

Comment: Good. Then use `parted` or for a terminal version use `parted`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

1. Insert sd card
2. Open a terminal,

   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
3. Run it:

   ```
   sudo -i
   umount /dev/mmcblk0p6
   umount /dev/mmcblk0p5     
   umount /dev/mmcblk0p3           
   umount /dev/mmcblk0p2         
   umount /dev/mmcblk0p1
   gparted
   ```
4. In Gparted, create a new partition table on a sd card device:
5. Select a sd card device.
6. Choose: Device --- Create Partition Table.
7. The application displays a Create partition table on /path-to-device dialog.
8. Select a msdos partition table type.
9. Apply
10. Create a new partition.
11. Select an unallocated space on the sd card device.
12. Choose: Partition --- New. (The application displays the Create new Partition dialog)
13. Specify the size and the location for the partition.
14. Specify the type of partition.
15. Specify the type of file system for the partition.
16. Specify the label of the file system for the partition.
17. Click Add to add the create partition operation to the operation queue.

Comment: What should the file system type be?

Comment: The one you need. FAT32 - ExFAT. Compatible with Microsoft or Ext3, Ext4, only Gnu/Linux

Answer (score -1):

1. Go into the dash
2. Type "disks"
3. Choose the programs called disks
4. Choose your device
5. Delete all the partitions by selecting the blocks and click the minus sign
6. Select the whole partition and click format

A simple Disks can do the job. Hope it helped :D

Comment: This does only half the trick. It was stated that a unified partition is needed.